# Launch android secret code via B4A App

Tags: android, basic4android

How can i launch *#*#xxxx#*#* code with B4A?

Here is my code:

```
Dim st,stt As String
Dim su As StringUtils
Dim ph As Intent

st = "#"
stt = su.EncodeUrl(st,"UTF8")
Dim ussd As String = "*"&stt&"3646633"&stt&"*"stt&"*"
ph.Initialize(ph.ACTION_CALL,"tel:"&ussd)
StartActivity(ph)
```

After launching the app, it only showed the dialer. I want to launch engineering mode directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  ANdroid does not support USSD codes.  There's ways to do it on certain models of phones, but nothing that's universal.  USSD should be avoided anyway, its a legacy technology that was meant for the world before data plans.

Comment: This app lunch engineering mode directly on buttonClick

https://apkpure.com/mtk-engineering-mode/com.themonsterit.EngineerStarter

Comment: THere is no way that works across all devices.  USSD is not supported.  You may find a hack that works on some device and some dialers, but it is NOT possible to work generally.

Comment: In addition, the codes themselves are not the same across all networks, or all OEMs.